# Difference between noheadfoot option in the Geometry Package and \pagestyle{empty}

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, geometry

I am quite new to LaTeX and have been playing around with different packages. I would like to do away with headers and footers in my document and I realised that `noheadfoot` from the Geometry Package will not do the trick, but `\pagestyle{empty}` will. Why is that? According to page 10 of the documentation for the Geometry Package, which can be found [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en), `nohead` and `nofoot` respectively eliminate spaces for the head and foot of the page and I understand this to mean that my page will not have any headers or footers.

In particular, when I use `noheadfoot`, I can still see the page number creeping up from the bottom of the page - I do not really see the entire page number, just maybe half of it.

On the other hand, when I use `\pagestyle{empty}`, I do not see the page number anymore (as desired).

In short, I am not looking for a solution here (since I already have a solution), but rather I am seeking to understand in what way is `noheadfoot` different from `\pagestyle{empty}`. Anyone who can correct my (mis)understanding of what `noheadfoot` does will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page style controls what will appear in header and footer, and `geometry` options control how much space is reserved for each part of a page, including header and footer.

- `empty` page style sets the contents in header-footer empty, while keeps the space for them unchanged.
- `geometry` option `noheadfoot` cancels the space for header and sets the "distance separation between baseline of last line of text and baseline of footer" to zero (from the doc for option `footskip`, user manual of `geometry`), while remains their contents unchanged.

  - So if your header is non-empty, its contents will typeset, overlap with the first lines of the main body, and leave bad box message in log.
  - If your footer is non-empty, its contents will typeset, overlap with the bottom of the main body.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply! I kinda get what you are trying to say, but if the header and footer is "typeset beyond the page" for `noheadfoot`, then how would it be possible that I can still see a glimpse of the footer in my document?

Comment: Answer updated. Sorry I made mistakes in describing what `noheadfoot` will do before.

Comment: I see now. Thank you :)